# "Too few arguments" in Bourne Shell script

Tags: unix, sh

I'm very new to this. I'm simply trying to test for the existence of a given file, and touch it if it doesn't exist. Command line responds that I have too few arguments. Obviously I'm missing something here. Thanks for having a look.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Enter File Name
read filename
if [ -s $filename ]
then
echo The File Exists!
else
echo File did not previously exist
touch $filename
fi
```

Comment: there's a `}` instead of a `]` in the 4th line

Comment: That was my mistake typing it, however, the problem persists. Thanks for pointing that out, but it doesn't change the problem for me. = (

Comment: This works jus fine as it's written, I simply was not invoking it properly. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors, one is that you wrote `}` instead of `]`, the other one is that you should add a space before the closing `]`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Enter File Name
read filename
if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
  echo The File Exists!
else
  echo File does not exist
  touch "$filename"
fi
```

As michaelb958 suggested you should also quote `$filename`, because that would create problems for filenames with spaces inside `like this.html`

You said you're new to this, then I would suggest using an editor with good syntax highlighting, that would've helped you in spotting the problem.

Comment: Note on `[`: Quote parameters, as in `"$filename"`. Failure to do so with filenames containing spaces can cause interesting behaviour.

Comment: @michaelb958 Just attempting to run the shell script by typing it's name

Comment: @RossCournoyer It would help if we knew where *within the script* the problem was.

Comment: @michaelb958 I'm sorry I can't be more helpful here. = (

Comment: So after using the code in my answer you still get the error? What error is it? How are you invoking the script?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni This is truly embarrassing. I was not executing the shell script properly by typing sh <script name>. Instead I was only typing the name of the file itself, which had worked in the past.

Comment: How is your script named? Are you definitely invoking the script you think you are, and not something else with the same name?

Comment: If you chmod the script to be executable you can run it directly. `chmod o+x myscript.sh`

Comment: @RossCournoyer Glad it's solved. (Also, when chmodded executable, you'll need to invoke the script as `./name`.)